# Assign the value of a templatefield on gridview to variable

Tags: asp.net, gridview, templatefield

I  know how to get value the of a `templatefield` inside a `RowDataBound` event:

```
Control ctrl = e.Row.FindControl("Drop_Responsaveis");  
DropDownList ddl = ctrl as DropDownList;
ddl.items.add(something);
```

But I needto get it's value on a `button_Click` event... How May I do that?

**Solution by the @Siz S answer**

```
foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows)
   {
     string str = ""
     Control ctrl = gvr.FindControl("Drop_Responsaveis");
     if (ctrl != null)
        {
           DropDownList ddl = ctrl as DropDownList;
           str= ddl.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why someone tried to close my question without leave a comment telling the reason...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get gridview TemplateField controls as

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in yourGrid.Rows)
{
     Control ctrl = row.FindControl("Drop_Responsaveis");
     DropDownList ddl = ctrl as DropDownList;
     ddl.items.add(something);
 }
```

Comment: Worked just perfect man !! I updated my question with the solution, really thank you again `Siz S` !